# Mongoose : Failed to connect to mongodb instance, but mongo works fine

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, proxy, connection

I'm facing a quite odd issue today.

I have a `MongoDB` database working just fine on a remote server, say `1.2.3.4`, running on port `22222`.

When I use the `mongo cli` to connect via the command line interface, everything works as expected:

```js
mongo --host=1.2.3.4 --port=22222
```

But when I try to connect to the same instance using `mongoose`:

```js
var options = {
            server: {},
            replset: {}
        };

options.server.socketOptions = options.replset.socketOptions = { keepAlive: 120 };

mongoose.connect('mongodb://1.2.3.4:22222/test', options);
```

I get this error:
**failed to connect to server [1.2.3.4:22222] on first connect**

Anybody knows why?

FYI the all setup is in my company, which happens to have a corporate proxy.
I was thinking that maybe the proxy was the evil one in this case, but then why the mongo cli connection is working just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a db called test? And have you tried omitting the `options`?

i.e. `mongoose.connect('mongodb://1.2.3.4:22222/test');`

Comment: I do have the `test` database setup, although I tried your ideas, i.e. `mongoose.connect('mongodb://1.2.3.4:22222');`, `mongoose.connect('mongodb://1.2.3.4:22222/test');`, `mongoose.connect('mongodb://1.2.3.4:22222', options);`. Unfortunately the result is always the same...